# Understanding Class<?>

Tags: java, android, generics

I came across this code:

```
public class RestfulAdage extends Application {
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    set.add(Adages.class);
    return set;
  }
}
```

I do not understand what `Class<?>` means.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290982/java-class-type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Class<?>` refers to a class of unknown type. The notation uses an [unbounded generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) which places no restriction on the type of class that can be added to the Collection. For example the following would not work

```
Set<Class<String>> set = new HashSet<Class<String>>();
set.add(Adages.class); // type not allowed
```

Comment: but if that is true, then why did this fail: set.add("hello") <-- i thought it can take any type ?

Comment: @user3134565 - "hello" is string instance, not class instance. You can put in the set `String.class` but not a string instance. You could also put `"hello".getClass()`

Comment: ok i understand now, but what good is that for ? i mean, i can not think of a single good use for this can u  ?

Comment: you can place any type into the `Set` but its type isnt checked

Comment: hm, not sure what you mean, .. can you give example ?

Comment: Say you defined the type, then the compiler would complain immediately  as it would then enforce the type - see the example added –

Comment: a good example would be a dependency container, to do dependency injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection
generally that kind of thing are used when you are metaprogramming.

Answer (score 7):

Class is a parametrizable class, hence you can use the syntax Class where T is a type. By writing Class, you're declaring a Class object which can be of any type (? is a wildcard). The Class type is a type that contains metainformation about a class.

It's always good practice to refer to a generic type by specifying his specific type, by using Class you're respecting this practice (you're aware of Class to be parametrizable) but you're not restricting your parameter to have a specific type.

Reference about Generics and Wildcards: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Reference about Class object and reflection the (feature of Java language used to introspect itself): http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Answer (score 7):

In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard, represents an unknown type. The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable; sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice to be more specific). The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype.

The following sections discuss wildcards in more detail, including upper bounded wildcards, lower bounded wildcards, and wildcard capture.

for more information [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

Comment: could you explain me more plz

Comment: for more information :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 5):

It refers to gererics. I suggest you read a little on it. Basically, you know only at runtime what type of object you get to work with. For example, Class can be Integer, String or even YourDefinedClassType

read here http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/generics/

Comment: so does this mean that it can take any kind of object, such as string, integer, double ...etc ?

Comment: set.add("dd") failed, and only takes null... why is that

Comment: @user3134565 read about generics, not just what people tell you! You can't learn the easy way. you try to add an instance of an object, you need an instance of a class

Answer (score 5):

From : [Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)

> In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard, represents an unknown type. The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable; sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice to be more specific). The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype.

Check the link, you will find more exhaustive documentation, examples etc.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that you have a set of **classes** that belong to different **types**, and you have instances of different **classes** as well. So if you want to check whether these instances are **instanceof** one of these classes, you could iterate through these set and do the job. And for that kind of job, you better use a totally unrestricted set:

```java
public boolean checkClasses(Set<Class<?>> typeLessClassSet, Set instances){

    while(typeLessClassSet.hasNext()){
        Class c = typeLessClassSet.next();
        while(instances.hasNext()){
            Object o = instances.next();
            if(o instanceof c)
            return true;
        }
    }
        return false;    
}
```